# User uses "mark as spam" to delete email

Tags: email, spam, customer-service

I want to ask, what would be the recommended procedure for dealing with users who used "mark as spam" button to just delete emails.

Recently I have a user, who requested "password reset" email 3 times. He/she successfully changed the password, and then marked all three emails as spam.

This dragged down my Sendgrid reputation down from 98% to 85%. This is pretty bad, since any reputation lower than 80% is subject to be reviewed. I am thinking of writing an email to that user, to ask him/her to "unspam" the email. What do web masters usually do in this situation? Is there anything to watch out for?

**Update**

After one week, another user marked password emails as spam again. This led me into thinking someone is attacking our email reputation.

Comment: I'd send out an individual email to the user in question (from a non-generic address) and explain to them why they shouldn't be marking emails as spam. Then make a site-wide announcement to prevent others from doing it as well.

Comment: @DavidBlayney I tried it yesterday, but didn't get a reply. So I suspect that I should send email using the same domain as my company, as it might be marked as spam.

Comment: Just send it from an address like `lulalala84027_59385739204@hotmail`, they'll be bound to trust it. In all seriousness, sending it from a different domain with proof that it is a legitimate email might help. Maybe they didn;t get a chance to reply.

Comment: And now you have your personal email also marked as spam. Waw!

Comment: @davblayn No reply, too bad. Would you put it as an answer? Though it is passive and does not work this time, but I guess it is the only answer.

Comment: @lulalala Maybe I will...

Comment: Just curious: How did you find out that he marked your emails as spam? I thought this was technically impossible.

Comment: @Ivar Sendgrid provides such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd send out an individual email to the user in question, also a site-wide email to prevent other users from doing the same. Maybe make contact with the user using your personal email address (`lulala84027_59385739204@hotmail` ???).

If you want to get the user's attention, make a notice on your website's homepage explaining that marking emails as spam is a potentially destructive action

Answer (score 5):

How odd ... I can "answer" but I can't "comment".  Anyway...

Are you sure the user is doing it on purpose?  You don't mention what e-mail system you are using, but (for example) in GMail, the two buttons are right next to each other; the "delete" is a trash can and the "spam" is a stop sign.  In Yahoo mail, the "delete" is a trash can and the "spam" is an X.

Perhaps this user genuinely doesn't understand the difference between the two buttons.

Comment: The user is using Yahoo mail, and yes I think the user used it by mistake (not on purpose).